# Multi module Maven project with wildfly-swarm-plugin

Tags: maven, jboss, wildfly, wildfly-swarm

I'm trying to convert a multi-module project to wildfly-swarm. However I've no idea how to set it up properly.

When I run `mvn wildfly-swarm:run` from core directory, it starts the server and an error says it doesn't find my persistence unit. `persistence.xml` is in the `DBlayer` module so it makes sense.

I tried to run it from the root directory but it says the plugin swarm is not defined. So I tried defining the plugin in the `root` pom.xml instead of `core` module pom.xml, but the `-swarm.jar` cannot be created.

So how am I supposed to set it up?

This is my root pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>xxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>x</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <properties>
        <version.wildfly.swarm>1.0.0.Final</version.wildfly.swarm>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
                <artifactId>bom</artifactId>
                <version>${version.wildfly.swarm}</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <modules>
        <module>backgroundServices</module>
        <module>core</module>
        <module>DBLayer</module>
        <module>userArea</module>
    </modules>

    <dependencies>    
        <!-- Java EE 7 dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Wildfly Swarm Fractions -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
            <artifactId>jpa-mysql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
            <artifactId>logging</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Then I added to core.xml:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-swarm-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${version.wildfly.swarm}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>package</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

core pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <parent>
        <groupId>xxx</groupId>
        <artifactId>x</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>core</artifactId>

    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
                    <artifactId>wildfly-swarm-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${version.wildfly.swarm}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>package</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xxx</groupId>
            <artifactId>DBLayer</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xxx</groupId>
            <artifactId>backgroundServices</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

DBlayer pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <groupId>xxx</groupId>
        <artifactId>x</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <artifactId>DBLayer</artifactId>
</project>
```

I didn't specify any main method though. I just have a persistence.xml in DBLayer under :

> DBLayer/src/main/resources/META-INF

So I'm kinda assuming that swarm takes care automatically to define the driver and datasource. What I mean is that in wildfly full you have to define the driver and the datasource in standalone.xml. Here I did nothing of that, so maybe that's actually the issue. However in their example they don't do it either. https://github.com/wildfly-swarm/wildfly-swarm-examples/blob/master/jpa/jpa-war/src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml

Here is my persistence unit:

```
<persistence version="2.1"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="my-pu" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>java:/walbangDbDS</jta-data-source>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <shared-cache-mode>DISABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>

        <properties>
            <!--<property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>-->
            <!--<property name="javax.persistence.sql-load-script-source" value="sql_scripts/loading_script.sql"/>-->
            <property name="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans" value="true"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a multi-module Maven project, remember to launch Maven commands directly from the root POM.

First of all, keep the `wildfly-swarm-plugin` declaration inside the WAR module, it would be inappropriate to have it anywhere else, since it applies to a WAR project. Then, you need to install the module `DBLayer` so that the module `core` (which is your WAR) can see it (and thus, can see its `persistence.xml`). Finally, you need to make sure to invoke the goal `wildfly-swarm:run` only in the WAR module by using the [`-pl`](http://blog.sonatype.com/2009/10/maven-tips-and-tricks-advanced-reactor-options/) command-line switch.

As such, from the root POM, invoke the command:

```
mvn clean install && mvn -pl core wildfly-swarm:run
```

This will correctly build your multi-module project and run the WAR with the Wildfly Swarm Plugin. You can find a working example of such a set-up [on this GitHub repo](https://github.com/hwellmann/wildfly-swarm-example-multi-module).

Comment: I didn't read the stacktrace well enough, My bad that didn't do it. but I'm onto something I think

Comment: @Ced Is the datasource correctly created in `standalone.xml`? Do you have a `faces-config.xml` (I see you're using the JSF dependency)? At least, with a minimal set-up, removing `jta-data-source`, `exclude-unlisted-classes` and `shared-cache-mode` in the `persistence.xml` makes the WAR starts fine.

Comment: No I didn't put any standalone.xml anywhere so my password and user to access mysql is not defined anywhere, neither is my datasource (neither do they in the doc/examples). As far as I understand it's not possible to do with a war file because it uses the default dataSource ExampleDS. So I'm now trying to deploy it as a .jar but I think it fails auto discovery of fractions (jsf and such) so it looks like it needs heavy setup just to define a datasource..